# Using sed to modify a header

Tags: sed

Supposed I had a file that has the header:

```
exm2240_T exm4561_G exm1916_0 exm490_1 rs67856512_A
```

I was wondering how to get the header to appear like this using sed:

```
exm2240 exm4561 exm1916 exm490 rs67856512
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the underscore and the character that follows it:

```
sed 's/_.//g'
```